# What should the key() method do if I implement a Iterator class to encapsulate a PDOStatement

Tags: php, pdo, iterator

I developed a interface and class to shield the PDOStatement.

The interface:

```
interface ResultSetInterface extends Iterator
{
    public function count();
    public function all();
}
```

The class:

```
class ResultSet implements ResultSetInterface
{
    /**
     * @var PDOStatement
     */
    protected $pdoStatement;

    protected $cursor = 0;

    protected $current = null;

    private $count = null;

    public function __construct($pdoStatement)
    {
        $this->pdoStatement= $pdoStatement;
        $this->count = $this->pdoStatement->rowCount();
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        if ($this->cursor > 0) {
            throw new Exception('Rewind is not possible');
        }
        $this->next();
    }

    public function valid()
    {
        return $this->cursor <= $this->count;
    }

    public function next()
    {
        $this->current = $this->pdoStatement->fetch();
        $this->cursor++;
    }

    public function current()
    {
        return $this->current;
    }

    public function key()
    {
    }

    public function count()
    {
        return $this->count;
    }

    public function all() {
        $this->cursor = $this->count();
        return $this->pdoStatement->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

This works fine. But I'm not sure how to use the key() method which is necessary to implement an Iterator class. Any ideas?

Comment: `return $this->cursor;` ?

Comment: thanks, and the key will be used when?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php First example here shows when each function is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, about your interface, I think it would be better for you to extend `CountableIterator` as you want to add the `count()`method and there is a magical interface for that purpose in SPL.

About the key method. You have to remember in PHP every iterable content is an association of a key and a value. It is inherited from PHP arrays.

Iterator is a way to overload the `foreach`operator and as foreach as a sythax which is composed as `foreach($iterator as $key=>$value)` you have to give the key method implementation.

In your case you have two solutions :

- using the `$pdo->cursor`
- create your own attribute called $currentKey and increment it each time you use `next`method.